# Copy data based on criteria input using userform

Tags: excel, vba

Hi and thanks in advance I am new to excel vba and need help on some little problem

I receive an adhoc task from my boss to using excel vba to compile report. This task need 2 workbook to be using. 1 is source workbook: Product.xlsx and another one is targeted workboook:Report Template.xlsx

What I need to do is if all the criteria input in the userform is found in the source workbook it will copy all the related data. I managed to do so but the problem is the column index is set by me, I need help on this if there is a way to replace this column index by using looping or another way to do so.

The source workbook contain enourmous row of data and about 54 columns. The data need to be pasted on the targeted workbook is need to exclude some columns in the source workbook. Here is my code:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim erow As Long
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Fab, Test As String
    Dim Machine, Year, WW As String

    Fab = FabTextBox.Text
    Year = YearComboBox.Text
    WW = WWComboBox.Text
    Test = TestTypeComboBox.Text

    Set SourceSheet = ActiveSheet
    With SourceSheet
        LastRow = .Range("A4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    If Test = "Test A" Then
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("Report Template1.xlsx")
        Set DestSheet = wbk.Sheets("Cover")

    Else
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("Report Template2.xlsx")
        Set DestSheet = wbk.Sheets("Cover")
    End If

    With DestSheet
        .Columns(3).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End With

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        If SourceSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = Fab Then
            If SourceSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = Year Then
                If SourceSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value = WW Then
                    If SourceSheet.Cells(i, 9).Value = Test Then


                        erow = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row


                        'change the column numbers to the relevant number
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 2).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 3).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 11).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 4).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 12).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 5).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 13).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 6).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 14).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 7).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 15).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 8).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 16).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 9).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 17).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 10).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 18).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 11).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 19).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 12).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 20).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 13).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 21).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 14).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 22).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 15).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 23).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 16).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 24).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 17).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 25).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 18).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 26).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 19).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 27).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 20).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 28).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 21).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 29).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 22).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 30).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 23).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 31).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 24).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 32).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 25).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 33).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 26).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 34).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 27).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 35).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 28).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 36).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 29).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 37).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 30).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 38).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 31).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 39).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 32).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 40).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 33).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 41).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 34).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 42).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 35).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 43).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 36).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 44).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 37).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 45).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 38).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 46).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 39).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 47).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 40).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 48).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 41).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 49).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 42).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 50).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 43).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 51).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 44).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 52).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 45).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 53).Value
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 46).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 54).Value

                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
```

And because i know how many columns in the data set I tried to replace my code as shown belows but it does not copy as code above.this code only copy data from `SourceSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value`

```
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If SourceSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = Fab Then
            If SourceSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = Year Then
                If SourceSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value = WW Then
                    If SourceSheet.Cells(i, 9).Value = Test Then


                        erow = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                        'change the column numbers to the relevant number
                        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
                        For j = 2 To 46
                            For k = 10 To 54
                                DestSheet.Cells(erow, j).Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, k).Value
                            Next k
                        Next j
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the data in two operations:

```
Dim rwSrc as Range   

For i = 2 To LastRow
    Set rwSrc = SourceSheet.Rows(i)
    If rwSrc.Cells(4).Value = Fab Then
        If rwSrc.Cells(6).Value = Year Then
            If rwSrc.Cells(7).Value = WW Then
                If rwSrc.Cells(9).Value = Test Then

                    erow = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                    With DestSheet.rows(erow)
                        .cells(1).Value = rwSrc.Cells(2).Value
                        'adjust the 50 to match your actual data
                        .cells(2).Resize(1, 50).Value = rwSrc.Cells(10).Resize(1, 50).Value
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: It is superfast to copy the data, thanks for your help